# Node.js exporting modules in app.js vs including app.js in individual modules

Tags: database, node.js, express

So I'm in the process of separating my express app into modules, and I have a question.

Currently my app.js contains:

```
var db = module.exports.db = require('./helpers/db')(app.set('database'))
```

and model files contain:

```
var DB = require('../app').db;
```

After reading [This](http://dailyjs.com/2012/01/26/effective-node-modules/), it seems like one way to structure the modules would be to export app and require app from within the module, and then require that module directly down the road.

That would mean in my db.js I would require require('../app'), and in my models I would db = require('db').

Currently db.js returns a new instance of a mysql connection:

```
 module.exports = function(settings) {
return new MysqlDB(settings);
```

}

Am I wrong to believe moving module.exports.db out of app.js, and requiring db.js directly in each model would create multiple instances of the connection?

I wrote this a little confused myself, so please let me know where I can improve the question. **Any and all tips are welcome**, I really want to get a better understand of it all.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would lean towards pushing the requirement into the module as opposed to the module having to be aware of where to grab an instance of the db object. This reduces coupling and makes it easier to inject a mock db object for testing purposes.

Comment: Great tip, just a little confused on how it would work.
Currently I have app.js require routes, the routes file requires a bunch of controllers and maps the url to the correct methods.

Inside the controller I include the model file, I don't assume I would pass the db to the model file from the controller, correct? (that too seems against your suggestion)

Just not sure where I would put the logic